# WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: centos, chrome, xvfb

I am trying to execute test scripts using Protractor, Google Chrome headless browser testing facility and xvfb on a Virtual Machine. I am running the command "npm run test:xvfb" to achieve this. But the browser fails to launch and crashes. Error log is attached below.

[image]

My Environment:

OS: CentOS 7

Google Chrome: ver 58

Chrome driver: 2.29

Node: 7.10

npm: 4.5

The fact that there is no detailed logging makes it difficult to identify the reason for crash. Please suggest possible solutions.

I have tried out few options, but no luck:

- Ensured `directConnect: true` in protractor.config.js
- Tested on multiple Chrome versions such as 58 and 56.
- Tested with both super user and non-super user.